# Unresolved external symbol error on variadic template c++ due to usage of unsigned int

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I've declared a simple function with variadic template.

```
template<typename ...Args>
void Log(const LogLevel level, const char * format, Args ...args);
```

Upon calling it in the following manner -

```
Log(LogLevel::debug,
        R"(starting x, %d pending call for "%s" with param "%s")",
        id, first.c_str(),
       second.c_str())
```

where the variable types are : `id` (`unsigned int`), `first` (`std::string`) , `second` (`std::string`)

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Log<unsigned int,char const *,char const *>(enum LogLevel,char const *,unsigned int,char const *,char const *)"
```

When I remove the `unsigned int` argument from the function call - the error disappears. 
AFAIK the variadic template does support different types... so what am I missing?

Comment: "I've declared a simple function with variadic template." And where and how did you define it?

Comment: If your template function *definition* is *not* in a header file, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). Otherwise, post a [mcve].

Comment: Missed this! Thanks for the link to the relevant post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a linker error, so (I suppose) you have declared the template function in a header file and defined it in a c++ (not header) file.

If you use the template function that receive the `unsigned int` in a different c++ file, the compiler doesn't know which versions of the function to implement.

Simple solution: declare and define the template functions/classes/structs in the headers.

If I'm wrong... please prepare a minimal example to replicate the error.